# collection_select not filtering (in nested_form w/nested resources)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, nested-resources

I've got an application that uses nested resources (see routes.rb below) to completely segregate users.  It works great until I use collection_select to allow users to select objects from other models.  For example, if I visit the store index view as user A, I only see stores created by user A.  However, if I visit the store_group view and try to select a store to add to the group from the collection_select menu under the `fields_for :store_group_details`, I see all stores created by all users.

As far as I can tell, the problem might happen because there is no filter for stores in the store_group controller.  store_group_details doesn't have a controller, but from what I've read, that seems to be correct since the model can only be accessed through a nested form in the store_group view.  I have another situation where another view for another resource has several collection_select menus for selecting objects from other models, and all of those have the same problem (they display all objects in that model, regardless of which user created them).

How can I filter the objects shown in the collection_select menus?  Is it a problem with what I'm passing into collection_select, or is it because the controllers don't do anything to filter the other models before those models' objects are displayed?  I've looked at the docs for collection_select, and couldn't make it work based on that.

Thanks for your help, I've spent quite a bit of time trying to get this to work.

**user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :store_groups
  has_many :stores
  has_many :store_group_details
end
```

**store.rb**

```
class Store < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many   :store_group_details
  has_many   :store_groups, :through => :store_group_details
end
```

**store_group.rb**

```
class StoreGroup < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many   :store_group_details, :inverse_of => :store_group
  has_many   :stores, :through => :store_group_details

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :store_group_details

  attr_accessible :store_group_details_attributes

end
```

**store_group_detail.rb**

```
class StoreGroupDetail < ActiveRecord::Base  
  belongs_to :store
  belongs_to :store_group
  belongs_to :user

  attr_accessible :store_id

  delegate :store_name, :to => :store

end
```

**_store_group_form.html.erb**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="span8">

    <%= nested_form_for([@user, @store_group]) do |f| %>

      <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>

      <%= f.label "Store Group Name (required)" %>
      <%= f.text_field :store_group_name %>

      <%= f.label "Store Group Description" %>
      <%= f.text_area :store_group_description %>

      <%= f.fields_for :store_group_details  %>
      <p><%= f.link_to_add "Add store to group", :store_group_details %></p>
        <br>
      <%= f.submit "Submit", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>

    <% end %>

  </div>
</div>
```

**_store_group_detail_fields.html.erb**

```
<p>
  <%= f.label "Select Store:" %>
  <%= f.collection_select :store_id, Store.order(:store_name),
           :id, :store_name, include_blank: true %>
  <%= f.link_to_remove "remove" %>
</p>
```

**routes.rb**

```
resources :users do
  resources :stores
  resources :store_groups
  resources :store_group_details
end
```

Answer (score 0):

There must be a problem with your controller. Did you ever solve this issue?
Look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8414035/rails-3-1-not-rendering-the-fields-for-from-nested-form) as it might lead to a solution. Or add you stores_controller.rb.